# WebAudioAPI: PannerNode: What value is represented by `orientation` and `forward`

Tags: javascript, audio, spatial, web-audio-api

I'm using a `PannerNode` from WebAudioAPI. Among others it contains `orientation` `X`/`Y`/`Z`. Also, the `Listener` contains a `forward` `X`/`Y`/`Z`.

Both, `orientation` and `forward` are represented by a value of (-3.4028235e38, 3.4028235e38).
[source](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#Spatialization)

**Question**
What do these values represent?

I thought orientation and forward were directional vectors that would be `1` in length. Instead they have the *weird* maximum value of +/-34028....

edit:

**What I've done**

I've checked [Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PannerNode) and [W3C's information](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#Spatialization). However, the following questions remain:

- Perhaps `orientation` and `forward` mark a point in the coordinate system?
- If that's the case, what is the coordinate's anchor? ((0,0) or `position` - i.e. are the coordinates relative to the position?)
- If orientation is a "coordinate point", why would you need `maxDistance`? I'd say the value is inferred by the coordinates of `orientation`

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the WebAudio spec on [spatialization](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#Spatialization-background).  There are diagrams there that show what the forward, up, and orientation vectors mean.  They are, in fact, direction vectors.  The magnitude doesn't matter.  The meaning of these is in the section on ["Azimuth and Elevation"](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#azimuth-elevation), but it might be a bit hard to extract out the parts you're interested in.

`maxDistance` is used to clamp the attenuation after some point.  This is based on the distance between the listener (AudioListener positionX/Y/Z) and the source, (PannerNode positionX/Y/Z).  This is described in ["Distance Effects"](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#Spatialization-distance-effects) along with the [`DistanceModelType`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#enumdef-distancemodeltype).